# Inner side by side Divs resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-resizable

I am new to html5, javaScript and jquery and stuck in a problem related to resizing and need help from the experts.

Problem is that I have a div inside which I have three divs.
1st is the title div on the top,and the other two are side by by side under the title div.The two side by side divs are placed such that one of them take 25% the space of outer div.and other one take 75% of width.

Now I want that when I resize my outer divs the inner divs should adjust them selves such that there width ratio remains the same.

But I am unable to achieve this.

So far I have done this

[Resizing Div](http://jsfiddle.net/xV28s/)

Can any one please guide me.What I am doing wrong.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest breaking your styles down into classes. It makes things much easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crude answer is to just use percentages for your widths: http://jsfiddle.net/xV28s/1/

You should move all those style elements into the css though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CSS:

```
#parent { overflow: auto; }
#inner-left { float: left; width: 25%; }
#inner-right{ float: right; width: 75%; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="title">Title</div>
    <div id="inner-left">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="inner-right">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```